# Get date of MongoDB server using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I want to get the current date on MongoDB Server from nodejs.

I am not using Mongoose.

In the monogd console, I can write Date() & I get it.

But how do i use mongodb driver & get date from mongo DB.

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = config.db;


function connectDB (callback)
{
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) 
  {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  }
  else 
  {
    console.log('Connection established to', url);
  }

    callback(err,db);
        });
}

exports.getServerDate = function()
{
        connectDB(function (err,db){

        if(err) {return err;}

        // What do i write here ?? .. db.Date();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could make a fake query - just to get dateTime value, use existing collection name (to avoid getting emty results).

AFAIK - there is no equivalent from sql word: `select getdate()`

```
var project = {
    "$project" : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "dateTime" : {
            $add : new Date()
        },
    }
};

var limit = {
    $limit : 1
}

db.existingCollectionName.aggregate([project, limit]);
```